# How do I define a dependencies.py file for an ML Endpoint instance for inference in Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, azure-devops

So, when I create an Endpoint instance for inferencing, it asks me for a *scoring_script.py* file (which I provide, no problems), but inside of it, I have a dependency that must be met.

My instance is crashing, because the image I've selected for [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) work doesn't have all Azure SDK dependencies, and I need to add custom dependencies. This "dependencies / add file" button asks me for a Python file, not a requirements text file or a [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)) [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) file, so I don't know how to define this script.

How can I specify these dependencies in a script? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: One way I can thunk of is to create setup.py with all your required packages as per my answer here-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76352244/how-to-create-diff-environments-for-different-python-packages-in-production/76355878#76355878  OR Directly use Azure ML SDK code as given in this blog- https://azure.github.io/azureml-cheatsheets/docs/cheatsheets/python/v1/environment/#in-azure-ml-sdk

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: That answer is now deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was an UX problem on the Azure platform. The dependencies file was actually an environment .yml Conda file, for example:

```
name: pytorch_env
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - numpy
  - matplotlib
  - pandas
  - scikit-learn
  - tqdm
  - pytorch
  - torchvision
  - pip
  - pip:
      - torchsummary
      - tensorboard
```

I have no idea why the filechooser asks for a .py file, but apparently, it's only to confuse developers like me :).